# Few HTTPS requests are not able to capture in Transparent mode running MITM Proxy

Tags: mitmproxy

I am running MITMProxy in transparent mode with below command

```
./venv/bin/mitmdump --mode transparent -p 8081  -s http_monitor.py --showhost --set spoof-source-address --ssl-insecure
```

**MITM version** is:

```
Mitmproxy: 6.0.0.dev
Python:    3.6.0
OpenSSL:   OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
Platform:  Linux-3.13.0-135-generic-x86_64-with-debian-jessie-sid
```

I installed the MITM certificate in chrome browser in one of my connected mac machine and I am able to see all HTTP and HTTPS traffic but there are few HTTPS requests which I am able to capture in mitm proxy even I did not see any error on console for those urls. I don't know How those requests been sent to without passing through MITM Proxy.

Below are few requests which I am not able to capture and not able to see how they are passed.
Could you please help to capture those kind of requests?

https://ade.googlesyndication.com/ddm/activity/dc_oe=ChMI_sfLyZ_V6gIVzrd-Ch3cFQkaEAAYACD7sds_QhMIkK3IyZ_V6gIV9CutBh2tcQRX;met=1;ecn1=1;etm1=0;eid1=13;

https://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=stickyxchange_dbm&google_hm=OGI2MGI3ZGIxMmMyNjNjOGUxY2ZiN2ZhYzM0OWVmNQ==

https://ade.googlesyndication.com/ddm/activity/dc_oe=ChMIxtzihaHV6gIVTFlyCh0yUw1iEAAYACD7sds_QhMI98jfhaHV6gIV0wBMCh0CDgE1;met=1;ecn1=1;etm1=0;eid1=18;

Comment: Have you considered that some apps do certificate pinning, or use a custom certificate trust store (e.g. they have a built-in trust store that does not contain your mitmproxy root certificate)?

Comment: I am not sure about that but I installed the MITM certificate at machine level so assuming mitmproxy will capture all traffic. If it is the case of certificate pinning then is there any way to see all https requests?

Comment: There is no generic way to see all traffic. You have to examine each program you are interested in and check if you have redirected the correct ports, if it trusts the mitm cert and finally if certificate pinning is used.

Comment: I do run below commands to redirect traffic to MITMProxy:
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to <proxy IP>:8081

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s $<deviceip> --match multiport --dports 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8081
Are there other port that I can check if packets are going out through that port.

Comment: Please do not add lengthy commands in comments. In the comments they become totally unreadable. This is not a forum, edit your question instead and lost them there.